# python -m build fails due to syntax error in `long_description`

Tags: python, restructuredtext, pyproject.toml

I am failing to get my README.rst file to be working for my long_description within the pyproject.toml file.  I am unclear why (advice appreciated, thank you).

I have a pyproject.toml file:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "growbuddies"
version = "2022.12.0"
readme = "README.rst"
description = "Buddies to help maximize the growth of plants in your indoor garden."
dependencies = [
    "influxdb ~=5.3.1",
    "paho_mqtt ~=1.6.1",
]

[project.urls]
"Homepage" = "https://github.com/solarslurpi/GrowBuddies"

[project.scripts]
get-readings = "growbuddies.__main__:main"
```

The [project] tables notes readme = "README.RST".  At the same directory level as pyproject.toml, I have an EMPTY README.rst file.

I run  `$ twine check dist/*`

and get:

```
Checking dist/growbuddies-2022.11.28-py3-none-any.whl: FAILED
ERROR    `long_description` has syntax errors in markup and would not be rendered on PyPI.                               
         No content rendered from RST source.                                                                            
WARNING  `long_description_content_type` missing. defaulting to `text/x-rst`.                                            
Checking dist/growbuddies-2022.12.0-py3-none-any.whl: FAILED
ERROR    `long_description` has syntax errors in markup and would not be rendered on PyPI.                               
         No content rendered from RST source.                                                                            
Checking dist/growbuddies-2022.11.28.tar.gz: PASSED with warnings
WARNING  `long_description_content_type` missing. defaulting to `text/x-rst`.                                            
WARNING  `long_description` missing.                                                                                     
Checking dist/growbuddies-2022.12.0.tar.gz: PASSED with warnings
WARNING  `long_description` missing.
```

Comment: What is the question? -- Remove the `readme` field from the `pyproject.toml` file if you do not need it, no need to use an empty `README.rst` file.

Comment: My question is regarding the long_description.  I want the README.rst to contain the long_description as described in the PEP.  The challenge is the rejection of the README.rst file why is that?

Comment: Hello grumpy person (in my opinion).  I had done that first.  As I pointed out, I still cannot get the .rst file to work, only README.md .  Please find many things to smile about.

Answer (score 1):

I changed to README.md for some reason, this worked.